# How to find the value $k$ of the line $x=k$ that Bisects the Area Under any Real Curve

Tags: integration, functions

As the title states; that is the problem. I am aware of the 1st Moment - however for $f(x) = x$ there is a small deviation from $1/2$ the area which is proportional to the range specified in the integral. For all similair functions this is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a, b$ be the lower bounds of $x$ for the region that you want to bisect. You then have to solve $$\int_a^kf(x)dx = \int_k^bf(x)dx$$ Let the integral of $f(x)$ be $F(x)$. Then this is $$F(k)-F(a)=F(b)-F(k) \to F(k) = \frac{F(a)+F(b)}{2}$$ Assuming $f(x) > 0$ means that $F(x)$ is monotonically increasing, so $$k = F^{-1}\left(\frac{F(a)+F(b)}{2}\right)$$